# Find the three dimensional line that goes through point p and is perpendicular to a plane

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am given the point $P(1,0,6)$ and I need to find a line that goes through $P$ and is also perpendicular to $x+3y+z=5$. Background info: I've gotten the help I needed now but when I started I was unaware about the method to find a vector perpendicular to the plane and how to find a line equation which uses that vector and goes through the point P.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem **and any attempts you have made to solve it**. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: You should change the end of the title from "line" to "plane", because: A. $x+3y+z=5$ is a plane. B. If it **was** indeed a line, then there were infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Well, if it was a line, there would still only be one solution. But you are correct that it is a plane. @barakmanos

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Haha, just realized that, using one finger for a line and another for a point... I was probably thinking of the "opposite" more or less (given a line in a $3D$ space, there are infinitely many lines that are perpendicular to it)... Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Fly by Night, I'm new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the normal vector to the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ is $(a,b,c)$. To find a line you only need a point and a direction. Now you finish it.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you now giving me the whole solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the normal vector is perpendicular to the plane, so I'm just going to figure out a formula for a line which goes through P in the direction of the normal vector.

Comment: And my final answer is **r** = <1,0,6> + t<1,3,1>

Comment: Your answer is correct. As I said, you need only a point and a direction. The point is given, and it is straightforward to find the direction. In general, the line passing through $P$ with direction $v$ is given by $X = P + tv$, with $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks again, it's a little counter intuitive for me to see that <a,b,c> is the normal vector, I'd imagine it'd be something like <-1/a,-1/b,-1/c>, but I'll remember that.

Comment: Let's think of planes through the origin, for simplicity, that is, $ax + by + cz = 0 $. The LHS can be written as the dot product $(a,b,c) \cdot (x,y,z)$. So, a point $(x,y,z)$ satisfies the equation iff it is orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Nice! I really like seeing those connections, it helps me understand the material on a deeper level. What is our d is not equal to zero? Like in the problem above, how come that still produces an orthogonal vector?

Comment: If $d \neq 0$, take a point $P$ in the plane. The point $(x,y,z)$ is in the plane iff the vector $((x,y,z) - P)$ is contained in the plane, and so, is orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$. You can determine $d$, by using that: $(a,b,c) \cdot ((x,y,z) - P) = 0 $ implies $(a,b,c) \cdot (x,y,z) = (a,b,c) \cdot P$. The intepretation for the LHS is my previous comment, and $(a,b,c) \cdot P $ is our $d$.